# Cannot delete node_modules created via npx create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, windows, webpack, node-modules, delete-file

I created a project through `npx create-react-app .` and started to modify and work, then I tried to delete it to create it again, because it was highlighting that some modules had syntax errors. I deleted all possible folders completely, but when I try to delete `node_modules` I get an error that the:

```
Visual Studio Code:
Failed to complete the deletion to the recycle bin. Do you want to perform a permanent deletion?
This action is irreversible.
**Delete permanently**
```

and if I delete it permanently I get the error:

```
Visual Studio Code:
Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, scandir
'd:\Desktop\proj-name\node_modules\.core-js-`code(I don't know if it's secret)`\features'
```

If I go to this path, it is an empty folder.

I've tried deleting via VSC, via moving a folder to the recycle bin, via `npm init -y` downloading one module and deleting again, via deleting specific folders, or at the end of a directory, and nothing has worked.

**PS** also file creation does not work in these folders

I also assume it's `webpack` related, because it contains many folders named `webpack`.

Answer (score 0):

all good, after a couple of days and a couple of restarts, the boot screen showed `"repair"/"processing"` of the `D://` drive, and when the PC was fully up and running, just moving the folder to the recycle bin got it deleted.